# Inserting into different columns depending on result from another table

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, case

I have one table, lets say called TABLE1 that has the following columns: filekey, empId.

In a second table, called TABLE2, i have the following columns: filekey, date (YYYY-MM-DD), hours, designation)

I am trying to make a new table, TABLE3, that has the following columns: empID,  designation, monday, tuesday, wednesday, thursday, friday, saturday, sunday

I need to insert into table 3 the rows from joining table 1 and 2. the following mappings are: table3.empID = table1.emp_id, table3.designation = table2.designation, table3.(monday-sunday) = table2.hours

So my issue is that i need to figure out what the date is and if it is monday for example i need to insert hours from table 2 into table 3 (empid,designation,monday). Whereas if the next row's date was thursday, i would need to insert that row into table3 (empid,desingation,thursday)

Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: what have you tried so far? you can do this over a derived table and group by at the main table prior to insert

Comment: in which language are you developping in sql?